# Very slow KVM in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I use Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and KVM, my CPU is Core i5 3.3 GHz and I have 8 GB of DDR3 RAM. I run Windows 7 in KVM and it's extremely slow. My co-worker use Debian on the same PC configuration and can run Windows 7 extremely fast! Where can be my problem?

> sudo cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/windows.xml

```
<!--
WARNING: THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE 
OVERWRITTEN AND LOST. Changes to this xml configuration should be made using:
  virsh edit windows
or other application using the libvirt API.
-->

<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>windows</name>
  <uuid>5c685175-baea-0ca6-591f-8269d923ffb8</uuid>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-1.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='localtime'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/windows.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:94:63:91'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='262144' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

UPD: I've enabled Intel-VT before installing KVM. I've also installed VirtIO drivers, so my Virtual Machine with Windows 7 has disk like this:
[image: screenshot of KVM virtual machines manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my little experience is better to use those settings(at least work for me)

```
type disk = qcow2
cache  = none
i/o mode = native
```

Maybe try

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Intel-VT engine in your BIOS settings.

Comment: It was enabled before I've installed KVM.

Comment: add more information about your answer or convert your answer as comment

Comment: I added the screenshot of Virtual Machines Manager into the question.

Comment: Why was this accepted as the correct answer @GuyFawkes

Answer (score 0):

Change "cache" (режим временных файлов) for virtio disk1 to NONE (from default)